# Create and use global view in C# WP8 XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, notifications, toast

I was trying to digg something on this topic before, but have no luck. What I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple, but seems to be hard to achieve :-)

I have a WP8 app (C# XAML) and I need to implement global messages (something like toasts) which could be displayed across whole application no matter of current navigation processes. Such toast message(s) should be displayed even while user is navigating between pages. To use the built in toasts is not a way (in case some other solution exists) since I'm possibly in need to have more than one message displayed at the same time (each one is independent of another) and should disappear after specified period of time.

So, my question is. Is there any way how to implement and use some kind of global view instance which sits above all pages and can be called from any page?

All I found until now is the possible ability to use PhoneApplicationFrame, but I would like rather avoid that if possible. I'm still unsure if this is even the way it can be done, but I suppose so. Do you have any alternatives or assurance this is possible and only way to achieve this goal?

Thank you all for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `UerControl` for the Functionality you are looking for. It is Control that has its own Seprate `Xaml` and `cs` file. You can call it from any page into your Project. UserControl provides the base class for defining a new control that encapsulates related existing controls and provides its own logic. You have a XAML file and C# class file for a user control. The class file extends the UserControl class and adds additional behaviours and properties. The XAML file encapsulates the composing controls, the styles, the templates, animations and whatever necessary to form the UI. Since it is a just composition, it is really easy to create. for more Reference you can go here [Why and how to create a User Control in Windows Phone](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone)

Comment: Hi there, problem is this doesn't solves the problem. User control can be called within the page. If I miss the need of creating new instance on each page then it does not fit my needs since object is destroyed once the page is left and so all the messages and possibly messages in the queue are also gone. And this is why I need to know if there is a way how to make it global, so to say above all pages, as a part of an application. Thank you for your effort anyway.

Comment: You can try popup that can be declared in APP.xaml.cs and can be called into all pages, check out whether it may fulfill your Requirement

Comment: Hello, using popup doesn't really help since it needs to be attached to some specific view. Thank you for your effort anyway. Seems there is no way other than to use toasts.

Comment: You can define popup in App.xaml.cs file and use it over the Application. here is a link that provide you guide to create popup using CSharp. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: OK, but will it last (will it be displayed) even between page animations/transitions? So far I read about it it needs to be instantiated on a page level, not Application code level. This is why it will not survive page transitions. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up rolling my own custom navigation using a single master page. As such any global controls are instantiated once at startup. Navigations are called from my viewmodels and result in usercontrols being removed and added to the visual tree as necessary (using transition animations to give the impression of page navigation) This works but im not sure whether it is best practice and would appreciate some opinions and comments on this. Certainly it solves the problem of global views described.